# Get the subdomain in a subdomain-route (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building an application where a subdomain points to a user. How can I get the subdomain-part of the address elsewhere than in a route?

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.project.dev'), function() {

    Route::get('foo', function($subdomain) {
        // Here I can access $subdomain
    });

    // How can I get $subdomain here?

});
```

I've built a messy work-around, though:

```
Route::bind('subdomain', function($subdomain) {

    // Use IoC to store the variable for use anywhere
    App::bindIf('subdomain', function($app) use($subdomain) {
        return $subdomain;
    });

    // We are technically replacing the subdomain-variable
    // However, we don't need to change it
    return $subdomain;

});
```

The reason I want to use the variable outside a route is to establish a database-connection based on that variable.

Comment: You can check the Request::server('PATH_INFO') and extract the string before the first dot.

Comment: True, even though it seems dirty while Laravel kind-of has that functionality out-of-the-box. I would like to find a cleaner way.

Comment: array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) Cleaner than that?

Comment: Nice and simple solution. `array_shift` only accepts a variable though, as it's passed by reference, but I used this instead: `list($subdomain) = explode('.', Request::server('HTTP_HOST'))`. A "Laravel-native" solution would still be nice.

Comment: I'm not in a position to try this but how about pass `$subdomain` to the route group function parameters? `Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.project.dev'), function($subdomain) {}` and then use `use` for `Route::get()`

Comment: @SamV The Route::group closure accepts a single argument, which is filled with a Router object. You can't start putting route parameters as arguments for closures until the Route::get() closure/controller method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Shortly after](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/14eb46bdbbe82a52306d7d2641d675383b444195) this question was asked, Laravel implemented a new method for getting the subdomain inside the routing code.  It can be used like this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.project.dev'), function() {

    Route::get('foo', function($subdomain) {
        // Here I can access $subdomain
    });

    $subdomain = Route::input('subdomain');

});
```

See "Accessing A Route Parameter Value" [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters).

Comment: how to call this subdomain like <a href="">Username</a> ?

Answer (score 10):

`$subdomain` is injected in the actual `Route` callback, it is undefined inside the `group` closure because the `Request` has not been parsed yet.

I don't see why would you need to have it available inside the group closure **BUT** outside of the actual `Route` callback.

If want you want is to have it available everywhere ONCE the `Request` has been parsed, you could setup an after filter to store the `$subdomain` value:

```
Config::set('request.subdomain', Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('subdomain'));
```

**Update**: applying a group filter to setup a database connection.

```
Route::filter('set_subdomain_db', function($route, $request)
{
    //set your $db here based on $route or $request information.
    //set it to a config for example, so it si available in all
    //the routes this filter is applied to
    Config::set('request.subdomain', 'subdomain_here');
    Config::set('request.db', 'db_conn_here');
});

Route::group(array(
        'domain' => '{subdomain}.project.dev',
        'before' => 'set_subdomain_db'
    ), function() {

    Route::get('foo', function() {
        Config::get('request.subdomain');
    });

    Route::get('bar', function() {
        Config::get('request.subdomain');
        Config::get('request.db');
    });
});
```

Comment: The reason for needing it outside a callback is to set up a database-connection based on the subdomain. I'd rather do this once for all routes, when a subdomain is present, than e.g. call a function inside every route. But yes, I expected it to be like you said: the request hasn't even been parsed yet.

Comment: You can apply a filter to a group then, i'll update the answer above.

Comment: What's the difference between this and using `Route::input('subdomain')`?

Answer (score 8):

Above won't work in Laravel 5.4 or 5.6. Please test this one:

```
$subdomain = array_first(explode('.', request()->getHost()));
```

Comment: For the later versions of Laravel starting 6.0.
Use:

`$subdomain = \Illuminate\Support\Arr::first(explode('.', request()->getHost()));`

Answer (score 3):

Way with macro:

```
Request::macro('subdomain', function () {
    return current(explode('.', $this->getHost()));
});
```

Now you can use it:

```
$request->subdomain();
```

Answer (score 0):

in the route call

`$route = Route::getCurrentRoute();`

and now you should have access to everything the route has. I.e.

```
$route = Route::getCurrentRoute();
$subdomain = $route->getParameter('subdomain');
```

Comment: Calling this inside the `group`-function returns `NULL`.

Comment: As i said, you need to be IN a Route callback to use this, not what the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN GET THE SUBDOMAIN LIKE THIS

```php
Route::getCurrentRoute()->subdomain
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

web.php

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.yourdomain.com'), function($subdomain) {
    
        Config::set('request.subdomain', $subdomain);
        
        Route::get('/',[WebsitesController::class, 'index'])->name('websites.index');
    
    });
```

WebsitesController.php

```
class WebsitesController extends BaseController
{

  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    return $request->subdomain;
  }
}
```